# How to pass the selected row data from jquery Datatable to Spring MVC controller?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, datatables

I have a `jQuery` datatable with one of the columns having an edit button.
On clicking the edit button I need to take all the values from the selected row to Spring controller .

I am able to get the row data from the datatable but I am not sure how to send this value to the spring controller.

Code for retrieving row data :

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
var data = table.row( this ).data();
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do an ajax request to your controller. Change type as yours i.e. GET, POST

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
var data = table.row( this ).data();
$.ajax({
       url:'your_path_to_post',
       data: {
          data: data //key data should be your model attribute name, value data is your table value.
       },
       error: function() {

       },
       success: function(data) {

       },
       type: 'POST'
    });
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer..!