# Spring boot - ModelAndView doesn't call another page

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot @Controller that redirect a page after ajax call. The code doesn't show error, but the new page not appear. Bellow I shared the pice of controller's code and the js function. Does anyone know what is happen?

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/openNewPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView openNewPage(@RequestParam String id, Model model) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("/newPage");
    return mav;
}
```

JS:

```
function open() {
    var table = $('#dataList').DataTable();
    $('#dataList tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        ligneSel = table.row(this).data();
        var id =  ligneSel[0];
    
        $.ajax({
            url : './openNewPage',
            type: 'get',
            dataType : 'html',
            data : {
                id: id
            },
            success : function(data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    $("body").html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Any errors occurred ?

Comment: Any erros in the console. Only the new page does not appear. Could you help me?

Comment: Mention where the newPage is located in your project, provide your project structure screen shot.

Comment: The newPage.hltml is in the  ./resources/template. It's so strange, because I use this syntax ito call others pages and work well. The difference  is I'm using a datable bootstrap, and when the user click the button, I get the row values by J's and send the datas to controller by ajax.

Comment: This is a question like mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328846/how-to-pass-the-selected-row-data-from-jquery-datatable-to-spring-mvc-controller. However, I think the person din't foward to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is the ajax call to spring boot controller does not redirecting a new view. The answer is that we need to **call the controller twice**.

This post will explain better the solution : [Ajax call to spring boot controller to redirecting a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970687/ajax-call-to-spring-boot-controller-to-redirecting-a-view) .

Thanks for all that helped me in this issue.

The exemple below show the solution:

**1) First controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/openNewPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView openNewPageController1(@RequestParam String id, Model model) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/newPage");
    return mav;
}
```

**2) Second controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/openNewPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView openNewPageController2(@RequestParam String id, Model model) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/newPage");
    return mav;
}
```

**3) The javaScript:**

```
function open() {
    var table = $('#dataList').DataTable();
    $('#dataList tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        ligneSel = table.row(this).data();
        var id =  ligneSel[0];
    
        $.ajax({
            url : './openNewPage',
            type: 'get',
            dataType : 'html',
            data : {
                id: id
            },
            success : function(data) {
                window.location.href = "/openNewPage?id="+id;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply naming the view will not redirect. Try adding `redirect:` prefix when you create the ModelAndView:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/openNewPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView openNewPage(@RequestParam String id, Model model) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/newPage");
    return mav;
}
```

Also, in your JS you are making a get request and getting a ModelAndView object.

This is not going to redirect the page to the ModelAndView.

AJAX is typically used like this to interact with a RESTful service which you can do a GET request and display data on the page in an async fashion - without needing to leave the page.

Spring has ModelAndView class in the MVC (Model-View-Controller) framework which follows the MVC pattern.
The Model and View are resolved server-side (Java) and then served to the client as opposed to fetching the data client side (web browser, JS).

If you want to redirect client-side (from the browser, JS) then add this to your javascript:

`window.location.href = '/newPage';`

You need to have the `/newPage` endpoint defined in your controller for this to work.

Try this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RedirectController {
    
    @GetMapping("/redirectWithRedirectPrefix")
    public ModelAndView redirectWithUsingRedirectPrefix(ModelMap model) 
    {
        model.addAttribute("attribute", "redirectWithRedirectPrefix");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/redirectedUrl", model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to reply, but I tried to use the "redirect" and it does not work. I use the simple model, returning a string, but it does not work too. There is others pages using this syntax and all works. I don't know why this particular page does not work?

Comment: You are making a async get request - not redirecting. Do you want to redirect or do you want to fetch an html string and set data on your current page?

Comment: I want to forward to another page.

Comment: Did you try adding `window.location.href = '/newPage';` to your javascript?

Comment: No, I didn't. Because I need to check some informations before forward to newPage.html.

Comment: I need to process the data before to redirect to the newPage. This is the main point that I need to return the controller and than go to the newPage. Could you suggest someting?

Comment: I am confused by what you are asking. There isn't much point to process data if you are redirecting to a new page unless you send that processed data to the backend - but I don't see that in your code. If you need to pass data in the redirect you can use a @PathVariable in the controller method signature and have the data in the redirect URL `/newPage?id=123`. If you need an example to follow to do that let me know and I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to understand me. Yes, I need to process something with that "I'd" in the JavaScript function in the backend. And I'm doing it. The problem is in the backend redirect the process data to a new page and show them. I didn't know why the spring boot isn't doing it by ModelAndView. I do it all the time.

Comment: Right - but in your code you are dynamically fetching an html string (ModelAndView) and updating your **current** page `$("body").html(data);`, you are not redirecting at all. It is still the same page even if the html changes. That is the point of using Ajax - you can fetch data and display it on the same page without having to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Spring BOOT app that uses [Thymeleaf templates](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html). For example:

[image]

I have a layout view that defines the menu, which loads another page by making a request to a Spring Controller. For example:

```
<a href="#" style="color: white" th:href="@{/photo}">Upload Photos</a>
```

When i click **Upload Photos**, it calls the **/photo** controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/photo")
    public String photo() {
      return "upload";
    }
```

Which returns the upload view in the Spring BOOT app. Using Thymeleaf templates, you can simply reference the name of the HTML file under templates in your controller, as shown in this example. Your issue looks like you are using AJAX, as opposed to using a menu item to reference the controller.

See this example for a complete tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do it. I"m using Ajax, because I have da datable and in with row the is a button. When I click, I get the row values by JavaScript, and the ajax send the data to controller and forward them in another page.

Comment: I have always used menu items to change the pages and then AJAX operations to POST data or to GET data that is then displayed in same page. It works very well in a Spring app.

Comment: I need to diplayed in other page. Using AJAX to call the controller and then call another page, does it impossible?

Comment: In my dinamic interaction with the final user, they choose the item in the datatable bootstrap and then the application get the row's datas in by javascrit and send to the controller by ajax call. The controller was called. I saw the user's datas chose. The spring boot read all the parameters before redirect to another page, but the page didn't show in the browser.